# Change CheckedListBox.SelectedItem Text

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Why does this not work? And why can't I find one single answer to this on all of Google and Bing?

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox.SelectedItem = "kshdfkjsdhf";
}
```

Obviously, the selected item is *not* null. No compilation or runtime exceptions are thrown, either.

Comment: What is your checkedListBox item Type ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash `System.String`

Comment: That should work then, Well, are you using third party CheckedListBox ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash No, I'm just using the standard Windows Forms CheckedListBox control. I'm too poor for a third party one lol.

Comment: @RohitPrakash Hold on, I checked the _type_ of `.SelectedItem` like this: `Console.WriteLine(checkedListBox.SelectedItem.GetType());` - that's the correct way, right?

Comment: type of the item is same, you are added in CheckedListBox.Items Collection.

Comment: I think you are trying to change the text of the selected item.. And I believe the property is not intended for such a thing

Comment: Also, if you want to check the selected item, you can use **checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox.SelectedIndex, true);**

Answer (score 3):

You can't set `SelectedItem` to an arbitrary string.

You should set `SelectedItem` to one of the **existing** `Items` in the `ListBox` or null to clear the selection.